# How can I convert print output to a csv and then upload it to a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets

I have a python script that prints lines in a comma delimited format.

The output currently looks like this:

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

I want to be able to take this output and append it to a Google spreadsheet.  If using Excel is an easier route, I would be open to that solution too.

Is creating a CSV and then importing to a Google/Excel the right way to go or should I look into another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing. I'm taking it you mean 'print' as in the Python statement or function (3+) which writes to the stdout for your OS.

I suggest you take a look at [13.1.csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

This documentation will allow you to write CSV's.

If you want to write to Google Docs it is going to require use of a Google drive API or networking.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into those.  Is appending to a Google spreadsheet easier than appending to Excel?

Comment: Not really. Appending to Google spreadsheet is going to require the API were as Excel is local to your machine. If this is an answer your happy with can you please accept it just so the question is marked and not listed as unanswered.